# I want to reduce the space between the cardview in grid adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is xml code. actually while running this code the output or the layout which I am expecting is not coming instead some different output is displaying. I have also attached the screenshot of the output which I am getting below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.247"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="151dp"
                android:layout_height="108dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="6dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="122dp" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
These are the snap of my outputs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the root view instead of `match_parent`

Also it's not right to use `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` in production, that will miss out your Views; instead hardcode the missing constraints.

I've fixed this in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="151dp"
                android:layout_height="108dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView15"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView4" />
            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```